# Share array or list between C++ and QML via property

Tags: c++, list, properties, qml

There's a list of unsigned ints in C++ class. The list can be modified inside the class in some way. There's a QML object that has to use this list. How should I declare the list to make the object able to use the values from the list and after changing the content of the list inside C++ get appropriate values in QML?

Currently the list is defined as:

`QVariantList cards;
Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList cards MEMBER cards NOTIFY setChanged)
void setChanged ( QVariantList const &cards );`

But QML takes only `cards` initial value (empty list) and does not "notice" any changes inside it later on.

Comment: Without seeing more code it's hard to know exactly what's going on here.  Are you emitting the notify signal when you change `cards`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for NOTIFY signal is optional. I guess it is for when we need to deliberately let QML know that the data is ready but the data will be consumed when it READs data. Aside from this we can almost always avoid programming NOTIFY. I even do rootItem->setProperty("propertyName", value) for occasional push in of new value to QML especially if there onPropertyNameChanged handler is ready.

The below will likely do what you want. Or it is required and adding NOTIFY to that won't hurt as well but adds 'inoperability'.

```
class MyMsgBoard : public QObject
{
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList cards READ cards WRITE setCards)
    const QVariantList & cards() const { return qvList; }
    void setCards(const QVariantList & v) { qvList = v; }
private:
    QVariantList qvList;
};
```

More detailed [explanation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html). I use message board concept from there.